# can someone help me with a wordpress plugin that can compare products like this http://www.whoishostingthis.com/compare/

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need a WordPress plugin that can do comparison of different services, like the one on http://www.whoishostingthis.com/compare/

Answer (score 0):

This is something that you will most likely have to program yourself. Mainly because there wont be many plugins that will go out to service provider websties, scrap the data, then aggregate it properly to compare on the field related to you.

In the sense of programming this you would want to do the following steps.

1. Determine what service providers you want to scrape
2. Scrape said providers for their prices (do it on a throttled basis or you will most likely get blocked by the providers website).
3. Aggregate the data and store it in a data store
4. Display the provider services while showing your comparison.

If you do not want to program this plugin yourself you can do a hybrid approach which requires a lot of manual intervention.

This site shows many "compare products" plugins that will allow you to compare 2 products in an ecommerce setting. If you use one of these plugins along with a wordpress ecommerce plugin you could manually enter each service provider as a "product" then display the product comparison.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/compare-products